# JavaScript - how to save the state of "this" properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I have the following code for js-learning purposes:

```js
function A() {
    var self = this;

    this.test1 = function() {
        console.log("A_test1");
        B().test2();
        return self;
    } 

    this.problem = function() {
        console.log("I'm never called");
    }

    return self;
}

function B() {
    var self = this;

    this.test2 = function() {
        console.log("B_test2");
        return self;
    }  

    this.problem = function() {
        console.log("I'm a headach and overwrite others in my free time");
    }

    return self;
}

/*
 * This is our "main" function like in C
 */
$(function(){
    A().test1().problem();
});
```

I have debugged the code with Firebug. Let's examine the line below from "main" function step by step : ***A().test1().problem();***

1) ***A()*** 
"The keyword "this" isn't a function(class) object. It is always the "window" object, that is extended line by line in the running time by the properties/methods of the current object (in our case: A's function object). So When we reach the end of A() (i.e. "return self"), the "this" object content is the following:

- all properties/methods of the "window" object
- test1() and problem() methods of A

2) ***A().test1()*** 
test1() method has the line "B().test2();". So it calls as next B()

2.1) ***B()*** 
When we reach the end of B() (i.e. return self), the "this" object content is the following:

- all properties/methods of the "window" object
- test1() method of A

  [problem() method of A gets lost, because it is overwritten by the problem() of B]
- test2() and problem() methods of B

2.2) ***B().test2()*** 
This runs as expected and is OK. So we are finsihed with A().test1().

3) ***A().test1().problem();*** 
And this calls the B's problem() method, although i want to call the A's problem() here.

So what is the proper way to save the online state of the "this" object?
(It's clear ,that "self" has no effect at all here since it is a reference (like in C) to "this" object.)

I could clone the "this"-object's state at the beginning of every constructor, i.e.:

instead of

```
var self = this;
```

how about that

```
var self = this.clone();
```

But i'm not sure if it's a good idea. Cause cloning the state of "this" for every newly created object would kill the memory in a large framework, wouldn't it?

I'm sure that i'm not the first person that confrontates with this problem. My Google searche gave me not much. So again what is the proper way to save "this"? How can i let A's problem() get called in this example instead of B's problem()?

Comment: you need to use `A` as constructor ie `var a = new A()`, then `this` will point to a new object instead of `window`

Comment: @ArunPJohny: Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use `A` as constructor ie `var a = new A()`, then this will point to a new object instead of `window`

Comment: Should i always call a function than by using the "new" keyword? Does it have any side effects ? (e.g. like creating duplicate function objects)

Comment: @moller1111 no, if you are working with objects as you are in this case you have to use `new`

Comment: thank you. i will accept your answer, because you were first and you answered the additional question as i wanted. For anyone who reads this comment: Please look at the other posts for "self" tip of "Umur Kontacı" and the recommended book link of "jdigital" below.

Answer (score 2):

```
var x = new A();
```

`new` keyword in javascript has a feature that sets `this` variable to the new instance. If you just use `var x= A();` than `this` in `A` function would be `window` (ie. the global context).

For these simple settings, you do not need to use `var self = this;` until you need a callback, but for convenience, you can do that without any side effects. Setting a variable's value to this to make it consistent is perfectly right and is very common, the variable's name is usually `that` instead of `self` but that's just sugar.

Comment: `Function.prototype.bind` can sometimes also be used.

Comment: @icktoofay `bind` is in ECMAScript 5; so it is not available on older browsers. Btw, how can you bind it to a new object (ie. replicate new)?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't saying you could replicate `new`. I was saying that rather than using a `that` variable you could use `bind`. As for browser compatibility, it is easily shimmed.

Answer (score 1):

If you call `new` on your function then `this` will, in fact, be an instance of the object and not the window... so...

```
function Foo(){
   this.whatAmI = function(){
         console.log("I am " + this);  
   }
}


var bar = new Foo();
bar.whatAmI();
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers ("use `new`") are right.

I think you would benefit from John Resig's works.  Take a look at his book ([Secrets of the Javascript Ninja](http://jsninja.com/)) or check out [the interactive Javascript tutorial](http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/) on his web site.

Comment: Should i always call a function than by using the "new" keyword? Does it have any side effects ? (e.g. like creating duplicate function objects)

Comment: No you shouldn't.  That's why I suggested looking at the educational materials -- so that you can gain a better understanding of how this works.